# Worklight 6 + Dojo missing files error

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have gone through this post to run an application in production, but facing an issue.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/the_dojo_library_in_worklight_studio_v6_0?maxresults=15&lang=en

I have created a Worklight 6 hybrid application, listed below is a series of tasks that I performed on it.

1. I built and deployed the project with the 'Provide Library Resources' checked and I get a list of missing files (a few stated below) in the dojo library requests console and the application works fine.

> [[2013-11-14 11:02:48] Application 'SampleBankingApp' requested a
>   missing resource. Providing library resource:
>         /dojoLib/toolkit/dojo/dijit/form/DateTextBox.js
>       [2013-11-14 11:02:48] Application 'SampleBankingApp' requested a missing resource. Providing library resource:
>         /dojoLib/toolkit/dojo/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.js
>       [2013-11-14 11:02:48] Application 'SampleBankingApp' requested a missing resource. Providing library resource:
>         /dojoLib/toolkit/dojo/dijit/Calendar.js]

1. I copied the missing files into the www folder keeping the folder structure as required, then I built and deployed the app with the 'Provide Library Resources' checked and I still get the same list of missing files in the dojo library requests console and the application also works fine.
2. Now I built and deployed by unchecking 'Provide Library Resources', when I tried to use the app it doesn't work, and the chrome console (where i use the mobile browser simulator) gives a series of errors like Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `404 (Not Found)`.

Whatever missing files it states in the dojo library requests console is in place inside the www folder, don't know whats going wrong.
I am using Eclipse Juno + Worklight6 + Dojo, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: In step 2, which resources are returning 404 errors in the Chrome console? Are they the same resources that you copied into the www folder in step 1?

Comment: yes the resources that were missing in the www folder before I added all of them, but even after adding it keeps on giving the same files are missing.

Comment: Are the files that you copied into the Worklight project under source control? If so, which?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be failing on copying the resources to the correct path in the "www" folder.

For example, if you are missing  /dojoLib/toolkit/dojo/dijit/form/DateTextBox.js, then you should copy that file into your_project/www/dijit/form